# Possessive case. Forming rules

Tags: grammar, british-english, possessives

Which one is correct? And why? Thanks

The Wright brothers made their official public flight in 1908 and amazed the world with their (aeroplane’s / aeroplane) flying ability.

Comment: aeroplane's flying ability = aeroplane's [flying ability]. _whereas_ aeroplane flying ability = [aeroplane flying] ability (and would be unnatural; just 'flying ability' would be idiomatic nowadays, but that usage is really predicated on the commonplace flying of planes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you are trying to say.

*Their aeroplane's flying ability* = the ability of their plane to fly.

*Their aeroplane flying ability* = their ability to fly a plane (but something like *their flying skills* would be more natural).

Comment: Can the second example be...aeroplane-flying....; I mean hyphenated?

Comment: Yes, it could be, but, as both Edwin and I pointed out, it's an unlikely thing for anyone to say.